# how can i deploy a scaleable zipkin deployment?

Tags: deployment, kubernetes, zipkin, opentracing

I found that the bottleneck of zipkin is collector and API, are these two components stateless so i can deploy multi collectors and multi API?

I want to deploy zipkin in kubernetes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are both stateless. You can deploy them using whatever horizontal-scalability construct is available to you.